# Android gradle plugin complains Uncaught translation error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm updating my kotlin version to 1.0.0-beta-2423, all what I did is update version numbers of related dependencies. But when I run assembleDebug task, it complains this error.

```
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: expected type java.lang.Object but found int
Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: expected type java.lang.Object but found int
2 errors; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

All my dependencies listed here:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.domain"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 3
        versionName "0.0.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':hermes')
    compile project(':widget')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk23:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4:$anko_version"
    apk "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.1.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxkotlin:0.30.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava-math:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.6.3-4'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
    compile 'pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location:0.8@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'

}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0-beta-2423'
    ext.anko_version = '0.7.3'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

What's going wrong here?

**update:**
The whole `build.gradle` is udpated

Comment: Could you please share the whole `build.gradle` file? It is not clear what Kotlin and Anko versions are used cause there are no definitions of both `anko_version` and `kotlin_version`.

Comment: @yanex Thanks for your attention, the `build.gradle` file is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to check the variables you are using, they are probably casted wrong somewhere.

`expected type java.lang.Object but found int`, is what that means.

Even though variables can be inferred in Kotlin, there are some possible cases where it cannot be like in yours situation. It's just that the IDE is not showing it.

I created an issue, please look at it for better context.

[Kotlin Issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10193)